# Question Regarding the Derivation of the Stratton-Chu Solution of Maxwell's Equations

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

I was working through R. S. Elliot's Book "Antenna Theory and Design", in which the Stratton-Chu solution for Maxwell's equations is derived. Essentially, these equations determine the electric and magnetic field within a region ($\mathcal{V}$) given the values of these fields on the surfaces ($S_i$) bounding the region and the distribution of sources within the region.

---

These equations assume a phasor representation of the fields and sources, and the notation I'm using is described below

Essentially, the electromagnetic quantities (fields and sources) are assumed to have harmonic time dependence so
$$\mathbf{E}=\textrm{Re}(\pmb{\mathscr{E}}(x,y,z)e^{j\omega t})$$
$$\mathbf{B}=\textrm{Re}(\pmb{\mathscr{B}}(x,y,z)e^{j\omega t})$$
$$\mathbf{J}=\textrm{Re}(\pmb{\mathscr{J}}(x,y,z)e^{j\omega t})$$
$$\mathbf{\rho}=\textrm{Re}(\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}(x,y,z)e^{j\omega t})$$
Which when substituted into (the differential) Maxwell's equations produces
$$\nabla \times\pmb{\mathscr{E}}=-j\omega \pmb{\mathscr{B}}$$
$$\nabla \times\pmb{\mathscr{B}}= \mu_0 \pmb{\mathscr{J}}+\mu_0\epsilon_0j\omega \pmb{\mathscr{E}} $$
$$\nabla\cdot\pmb{\mathscr{E}}=\frac{\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\nabla\cdot \pmb{\mathscr{B}}=0$$

---

Elliot derives the following equation for the electric field,
$$\pmb{\mathscr{E}}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathcal{V}}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}}{\epsilon_0} \nabla_S\psi-\psi\mu_0 j\omega \pmb{\mathscr{J}}\right)d\tau+\frac{1}{4\pi}\sum\int_{S_i}( (\pmb{\mathscr{E}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}})\nabla_S\psi + (\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{E}})\times\nabla_S\psi-j\omega\psi(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{B}}))dS$$
Where ($k$ being the wave number defined as $\omega/c$)
$$\psi = \frac{e^{-ikR}}{R}$$
Where $R$ is the distance from $(x,y,z)$ (the field point) to $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ (the coordinates over which the integration occurs, so all the fields within the integral are functions of these coordinates)

And the nabla operator in the integration coordinates is defined as ($\nabla$ represents differentiation with respect to $(x,y,z))$
$$\nabla_S=\hat{\mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}+\hat{\mathbf{y}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}+\hat{\mathbf{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$$

And $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is the normal vector at at each surface directed *inwards* (I know this is unconventional but it's what Elliot uses).

After this, Elliot claims that using the curl of the above equation in conjunction with Maxwell's equations, one can obtain
$$\pmb{\mathscr{B}}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_\mathcal{V}(\mu_0\pmb{\mathscr{J}}\times\nabla_S\psi)d\tau+\sum\int_{S_i}\left(\frac{j\omega \psi}{c^2}(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{E}})+(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{B}})\times\nabla_S\psi +(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\pmb{\mathscr{B}})\nabla_S\psi\right)dS$$

---

I don't see how this equation can be obtained directly from the above equation, and I've convinced myself that it's impossible as follows:

By Maxwell's equations, $\pmb{\mathscr{B}}=-\frac{1}{j\omega}\nabla\times\pmb{\mathscr{E}}$, thus taking the curl of the equation for the electric field and dividing by $-j\omega$ should produce the desired equation for the magnetic field.

I've gotten the volume integral to work out since
$$\nabla\times\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}}{\epsilon_0}\nabla_S\psi\right)=\frac{\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}}{\epsilon_0}(\nabla\times\nabla_S\psi)-\nabla_S\psi\times\left(\nabla \frac{\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}}{\epsilon_0}\right)=0$$
The first term is $0$ since the gradient of curl is always $0$ for well behaved fields, while the term is $0$ since $\boldsymbol{\tilde{\rho}}$ is a function of $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ not $(x,y,z)$ in the integral.

For the current source term,
$$\nabla\times\left(\psi\mu_0 j\omega \pmb{\mathscr{J}}\right)=-\mu_0 j\omega \pmb{\mathscr{J}}\times(\nabla \psi) =\mu_0 j\omega \pmb{\mathscr{J}}\times(\nabla_S\psi ) $$
Where $\nabla \psi = -\nabla_S \psi$ was used (this follows from the definition), and one of the terms in the expansion is $0$ because the curl is with respect to $(x,y,z)$. This matches the volume integral in the equation for the magnetic field once dividing through by $-j\omega$

Now for the surface integral terms, which is where I have an issue. The last term in the electric field equation is not an issue since
$$\nabla\times(-j\omega\psi(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{B}}))=j\omega(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{B}})\times \nabla\psi=-j\omega(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{B}})\times \nabla_S\psi$$
When dividing by $-j\omega$ this produces the middle term in the integral for the magnetic field.

The first term in the electric field comes out to $0$ when taking the curl since
$$\nabla\times((\pmb{\mathscr{E}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}})\nabla_S\psi)=(\pmb{\mathscr{E}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}})(\nabla\times\nabla_S \psi)-\nabla_S\psi\times(\nabla(\pmb{\mathscr{E}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}))$$
The first term has to be $0$ because it's the curl of a gradient, and the second term has to  be $0$ since the differentiation is with respect to $(x,y,z)$.

Thus, in order for the derivation to work out it's required that
$$-\frac{1}{j\omega}(\nabla\times((\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{E}})\times\nabla_S\psi))=\frac{j\omega \psi}{c^2}(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\pmb{\mathscr{E}}) +(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\pmb{\mathscr{B}})\nabla_S\psi$$
But this seems to be impossible, since the left side contains the electric field evaluated at $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ and a derivative with respect to $(x,y,z)$ while the right contains a term with a magnetic field (again as a function of $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$). How could this term arise if there's no way to differentiate the electric field? Is there another equation relating the phasor form of the electromagnetic fields without differentiation? Is there some mathematical trick I'm missing?

Any help on this problem would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the Appendix A of Elliott's book for the detailed derivation?

Comment: Yes, but the appendix only derives the electric field formula and doesn't discuss converting it to the relevant formula for the magnetic field

Comment: The equations are essentially symmetrical for interchanging $E$ with $H$; to quote Stratton and Chu "An appropriate interchange of vectors gives...", yes, truly it is a direct quote right under Eq 14 from "Diffraction Theory of Electromagnetic Waves", JULY 1, 1939 PHYSICAL REVIEW .

Comment: I understand that they're symmetrical in form, but I fail to see how the magnetic field equation is related to the curl of the electric field equation, which elliot describes as a valid method of deriving it

"Alternatively, the curl of (1.53, the electric field equation) may be taken and then (1.44a, maxwell's equation relating the curl of the E-field to the magnetic field) used to obtain B"

Comment: I see, Stratton and Chu actually derive their formula in a completely symmetric form including magnetic currents and charges. Do you have access to the original paper?

Comment: No, I'm working solely off of Elliot's text right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141814/discussion-between-hyportnex-and-bikrant-bhattacharyya).